# What is punishment (if any) for making another adult involuntary intoxicated with alcohol, no other actions and injury, USA?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, alcohol, drugs

I've tried to goggle, I only find intoxication defense.

I'm interested what is punishment (if any) for making another involuntary intoxicated with alcohol knowing it was alcohol and the goal was to intoxicate (force-fed maybe?). Suppose no further action to take advantage was taken and no intent to take any other action proven. The one fed had not sustained any additional injury as a result. Both are adult who can legally buy alcohol, both were sober at the beginning. The setting in not medical institution, no court order to provide substances as a treatment something, say it was in a bar if it matters a lot.

As another option, say small amount of money (like $5) was taken out of "victims" (I cannot say victim until it is confirmed such action is a crime at all, right?) pocket while intoxicated.

As a bonus, if you know what is punishment if alcohol is changed to drugs (over the counter, prescribed, illegal).

For clarity, let it be USA, though in somebody knows UK law but not USA, welcome to answer/comment. TIA

Comment: In the US this is going to vary significantly by state. Do you have a particular state in mind?

Comment: @David Siegel, nope. could you please give max and min? If not sure, just some examples. TIA

Comment: In the UK, various websites claim drink spiking itself is an offence ( https://www.devon-cornwall.police.uk/support-and-guidance/your-community/drugs-and-alcohol/alcohol/drink-spiking/ and https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/advice/staying-safe-while-drinking/drink-spiking-and-date-rape-drugs for instance) but it seems the law they link back to only states it's an offence "where A intends to stupefy or overpower B so that any person can engage in sexual activity involving B."

Comment: @Showsni see https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm5802/cmselect/cmhaff/967/report.html#heading-1

Comment: FWIW, forcing something to drink or eat something is probably a completely different crime (plausibly assault or hazing), than causing someone to be intoxicated by deception (e.g. slipping 151 rum into a soda without the knowledge of the person drinking it).

Answer (score 2):

There is not a uniform treatment of this act under US law. Although it could fall under the broad rubric of the common law tort of assault, that does not necessarily translate to the crime of assault, so there may need to be a separate law passed. There is [such a law in North Carolina](https://www.ncleg.gov/EnactedLegislation/Statutes/PDF/BySection/Chapter_14/GS_14-401.11.pdf), where it would be a class H or I felony, depending on effect. [This table](https://www.ncleg.net/enactedlegislation/statutes/html/bysection/chapter_15a/gs_15a-1340.17.html) then states the penalty – the actual value depends on "points" assessed against a person for their prior criminal record. The range is 3 months (Class I, low points and mitigating circumstances) and 25 months (Class H, high points and aggravating circumstances). Prior to Dec. 1 2019, drink spiking (with alcohol) was not a crime in NC, so the minimum at that time was zero. You don't specify whether the recipient is a minor, so I assume the recipient is a legal adult.

Comment: It can also constitute "tampering with food or drink" if you spike the punch, though again this isn't treated uniformly from state to state.

Comment: Thanks. Just saw a recent comment by @ohwilleke to the question that hints forcing to drink and deception (spiking) could be different "crimes". Does your answer cover both? TIA